# SignalR Message not sending - Angular

Tags: angular, signalr, azure-functions

I'm trying to send a message using SignalR and Angular, but the API never gets hit on the backend. No status code at all so it never makes it to API endpoint. The hub connection establishes fine so I would think it hits the endpoint automatically when executing `this.hubConnection.invoke('NewMessage', message);` but it doesn't seem to work. I'm really new to SignalR so I appreciate any help!

messaging azure function code

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  return {
    "target": "newMessage",
    "arguments": [ req.body ]
  };
};
```

function.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalR",
      "name": "$return",
      "hubName": "chat",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

angular service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { SignalViewModel } from "./signal-view-model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  signalReceived = new EventEmitter<SignalViewModel>();

  constructor() {
    this.buildConnection();
    this.startConnection();
  }

  private buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7070/api")
      .build();
  };
  sendMessage(message: SignalViewModel) {
    this.hubConnection.invoke('NewMessage', message);
  }
  private startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection Started...");
        this.registerSignalEvents();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error while starting connection: " + err);

        //if you get error try to start connection again after 3 seconds.
        setTimeout(function () {
          this.startConnection();
        }, 3000);
      });
  }

  private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.signalReceived.emit(data);
    });
  }
}
```

angular component

```
 txtMessage: string = 'd';
  uniqueID: string = new Date().getTime().toString();
  messages = new Array<SignalViewModel>();
  signalRMessage = new SignalViewModel();
  sendMessage(): void {
    if (this.txtMessage) {
      console.log("Executing signalr")
      this.signalRMessage = new SignalViewModel();
      this.signalRMessage.clientuniqueid = this.uniqueID;
      this.signalRMessage.type = "sent";
      this.signalRMessage.message = this.txtMessage;
      this.signalRMessage.date = new Date();
      this.messages.push(this.signalRMessage);
      this.signalRService.sendMessage(this.signalRMessage);
      this.txtMessage = '';
    }
```

negotiate function

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
  context.res.json(connectionInfo);
};
```

function.json of negotiate function

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "hubName": "chat",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, please add also your server side Hub code.

Comment: Don't think this is correct url `"http://localhost:7070/api"` You want that url to what you setup as the hub url in your startup `endpoints.MapHub<T>("/URL");`

Comment: He said that `The hub connection establishes fine` so I belive it made to the hub.

Comment: Here's a console log showing connection established: https://postimg.cc/WtxcFmbG Also I added negotiate connection azure function above as well

Comment: could you verify data is actually pushed to the client or not in the Network tab of the developer tools (or maybe enabling the logging on client-side). Look for URL that says 'connection?' in-network tab and checks for Messages with that call,

Comment: When I click the button to send the test message, the network tab doesn't output anything. It's giving the impression that an http call isn't made. I know the ```sendMessage(message: SignalViewModel)``` service method is getting hit because I put an alert in there an it output fine. So this line inside signalR service ```this.hubConnection.invoke('NewMessage', message)``` doesn't seem to be executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `"NewMessage"` with the capital "N" on the client side and "newMessage" on the function.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  return {
    "target": "newMessage", // "n"
    "arguments": [ req.body ]
  };
};
```

```js
 sendMessage(message: SignalViewModel) {
    this.hubConnection.invoke('NewMessage', message); // "N"
  }
```

Also take a look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config) about Azure SignalR Service in Serverless mode. As you can see, if your hub is configured to Serverless mode, you can't call methods from client.

> If you're using Azure SignalR Service in Serverless mode, you cannot call hub methods from a client. For more information, see the SignalR Service documentation. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-hub-methods-from-client)

**Update**: Since you are working on Azure Functions and you need to run SignalR on serverless mode, as you can see below you can't invoke hub methods from the client.

Comment: I created a new SignalR instance that runs in classic mode per your recommendation to not use serverless mode, but it returns https://postimg.cc/BXdnK88t   How can I get it to play nice with Angular client? I searched around for this error, but haven't found anything yet to give me an idea on how to get past the error. Also I updated from ```NewMessage``` to ```newMessage``` in signalr service

Comment: Since your developing with signalR on Azure Functions, I believe you server mode need to be serverless as you can see here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#signalr-service-configuration).

Comment: I didn't recommend you to turn off serverless mod, just I wanted you to see what documentation says about it.

Comment: You turned on the default mode, but that mode need a server to run.

Comment: My bad. I guess I misunderstood. You said ```if your hub is configured to Serverless mode, you can't call methods from client.``` If that's the case, then it makes it sound like Angular wouldn't work with serverless mode. I just reverted back to serverless mode. Do you have any recommendations to get the message azure function to execute now that newMessage is fixed? Currently when I hit the button in the client to invoke a message, the azure function console never shows any output. (never received)

Comment: Yes, you can't use Angular with serverless mod. I would create a simple .NET Core app that you angular will connect to it, and the app will just redirect  it to Azure SignalR. Then you can invoke the hub methods from the client.

Comment: So I can't use serverless mode with my current stack of Angular and Azure Functions. So that leaves either default or classic mode. Also I'm using Nodejs, not .Net. But that also means I would have to solve this issue when removing serverless mode: https://postimg.cc/BXdnK88t So I'm a bit confused on next steps. It seems like I got to fix the proxy error to get Angular working since serverless isn't compatible. Am I correct so far?

Comment: You can listen to methods from your Angular app, you just can't `invoke` methods in your current approach. Take a look at this: https://medium.com/@sibeeshvenu/realtime-iot-data-using-azure-signalr-and-functions-in-angular-cde795a825a

Comment: I managed to get the message to send and the message count goes from 0 to 1 in SignalR portal, but I haven't been able to subscribe to the new message. Instead it returns null https://postimg.cc/zyNfSyJG. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Updated Code:  https://pastebin.com/AVGaiJGy

Comment: @user6680 it is better that you open another question for that matter.  You question was answered that you had the method name wrong and the type of hub does not support angular. Now you have a different case, open another question and mark this as resolved.